# Orbit animation with raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, raphael

New to raphael.js, I'm looking for an explanation on how to do something like move planets around a sun in an orbit. I'm stuck trying to create a path and animate the movement of the circle around it.

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction!

Comment: Getting the right paths will be the challenging part.  Once you have that, it's easy to use the getTotalLength and getPointAtLength functions (both of which are element methods designed specifically to work on path elements) to find specific points in a path.  Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/gyeSf/17/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My friend @Kevin Nielsen is right, you'll want "getPointAtLength." There's a nice little Raphael function [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/Wsv3e/4/) that adds an .animateAlong() function, though it needs a little modification to work on circular objects. I stripped it to the necessities for you.

Assuming you recognize post-1609 astronomy, [you'll want elliptical orbits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion). (Though the difference in the short and long radii are quite small in reality, which is why Copernicus was a bit off the mark.) But you can't use the .ellipse() function, since you need the ellipse as a path in order to animate along it. See the SVG specifications for the [elliptical arc](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands), or just try a bunch of combinations until it looks right, like I did:

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500);

var center = {x: 200, y: 100 };
var a = 100;
var b = 80;

//see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands
var ellipse = "M" + (center.x - a) + "," + center.y + " a " + a + "," + b + " 0 1,1 0,0.1";

var orbit = paper.path(ellipse);
```

Now you want to draw the earth at one of the foci of the ellipse, and the moon along the path. We'll start it at the [perigee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perigee).

```
var focus = Math.pow(a*a - b*b, 0.5);

var palebluedot = paper.circle(center.x - focus, center.y, 25)
    .attr({
        stroke: 0,
        fill: "blue"    
    });

var moon = paper.circle(center.x - a, center.y, 10)
.attr({
    stroke: 0,
    fill: "#CCC"
});
```

And here's your modified "animateAlong" function:

```
//Adapted from https://github.com/brianblakely/raphael-animate-along/blob/master/raphael-animate-along.js
Raphael.el.animateAlong = function(path, duration, easing, callback) {
    var element = this;
    element.path = path;
    element.pathLen = element.path.getTotalLength();    
    duration = (typeof duration === "undefined") ? 5000 : duration;
    easing = (typeof easing === "undefined") ? "linear" : duration;

    //create an "along" function to take a variable from zero to 1 and return coordinates. Note we're using cx and cy specifically for a circle    
paper.customAttributes.along = function(v) {
        var point = this.path.getPointAtLength(v * this.pathLen),
            attrs = {
                cx: point.x,
                cy: point.y 
            };
        this.rotateWith && (attrs.transform = 'r'+point.alpha);
        return attrs;
    };    

    element.attr({along: 0 }).animate({along: 1}, duration, easing, function() {
        callback && callback.call(element);
    });    
};
```

and here it is:

```
moon.animateAlong(orbit, 2000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/Wsv3e/4/)

Comment: Can't believe this didn't even get a single upvote! Awesome explanation + fiddle, sir.

Comment: I am forced to mention that this orbit (from the fiddle) is not a variable-speed one (but it should).

Answer (score 1):

@Chris Wilson's answer is right on the money.

One slight modification I needed was to have the animation repeat indefinitely. @boom doesn't ask for it specifically, but as I can imagine this could be a common requirement for orbit animations, here's my modification to Chris's version of `.animateAlong()`:

```
Raphael.el.animateAlong = function(path, duration, repetitions) {
    var element = this;
    element.path = path;
    element.pathLen = element.path.getTotalLength();    
    duration = (typeof duration === "undefined") ? 5000 : duration;
    repetitions = (typeof repetitions === "undefined") ? 1 : repetitions;

    paper.customAttributes.along = function(v) {
    var point = this.path.getPointAtLength(v * this.pathLen),
        attrs = { cx: point.x, cy: point.y };
    this.rotateWith && (attrs.transform = 'r'+point.alpha);
    return attrs;
    };    

    element.attr({along:0});
    var anim = Raphael.animation({along: 1}, duration);
    element.animate(anim.repeat(repetitions)); 
};
```

Note that I've dropped the easing and callback parameters (as I didn't need them) and added the `repetitions` parameter, which specifies the number of repetitions to perform.

An example call (starting an endlessly looping orbit animation) is:

`moon.animateAlong(orbit, 2000, Infinity);`