# How to create a dynamic ellipse using paper.path object in raphael.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am a newbie to rapheal js & I need to create a dynamic ellipse only using paper.path() object.

Although we can do it using paper.ellipse(), but I need it to be done by only in path manner on demand of pre-exist code. I googled for it and only get the solution for circle2path().

Let me give a example to describe.

```
var paper = Raphael(10,10, 250, 250);
var start_x = 170;//this has to be dynamic
var start_y = 160;// so these are also
var r_x = 40;
var r_y = 35;
var ellipse = paper.ellipse(start_x,start_y,r_x,r_y);
// here instead of paper.ellipse, I need to use paper.path()
//for example I used path to create circle
var radius = 50;
var circle_path = "M"+ (start_x)+ (start_y-radius)+"A"+ radius+radius+0+1+1+(start_x-0.1)+(start_y-radius)+ "z";
var circle = paper.path(circle_path);
```

Its working properly for circle. Is there any way to do with ellipse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Eureka.........

I got a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341165/orbit-animation-with-raphael-js) .

```
var paper = Raphael(10,10, 250, 250);
var start_x = 170;//this has to be dynamic
var start_y = 160;// so these are also
var r_x = 40;
var r_y = 35;
var ellipse = [["M", (start_x - r_x), (start_y)], ["a", r_x, r_y ,0, 1,1, 0,0.1 ],"z"];
var draw = paper.path(ellipse);
```

This is it, what I want. So we can create a function for it.

```
var ellipse2path = function(start_x,start_y,r_x,r_y){
  return [["M", (start_x - r_x), (start_y)], ["a", r_x, r_y ,0, 1,1, 0,0.1 ],"z"];
};
```